# How can I make the color reverse application autostart when I log in?

Tags: compiz, color-management

The application make the color reversed when i type <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>. I don't know what 's its name, and how can i make it start automatically when i log in?

Answer (score 3):

The application you are using is called `compiz`. Settings can most easily be adjusted by installing the compiz config settings manager `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`, find it in System->Preferences, although this will not be able to do what you want. 
The plugin that reverses the color is called `Negative` (in the accessibility section of ccsm). 
A possible method to auto-call a plugin on startup is described here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9351609&postcount=8 (although that seems a bit involved)

(From comment) This should do it:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.compiz /org/freedesktop/compiz/neg/allscreens/screen_toggle_key org.freedesktop.compiz.activate string:'root' int32:$(xwininfo -root | grep id: | awk '{ print $4 }')
```

Comment: This should do it: `dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.compiz /org/freedesktop/compiz/neg/allscreens/screen_toggle_key org.freedesktop.compiz.activate string:'root' int32:$(xwininfo -root | grep id: | awk '{ print $4 }')`